# Проблема с микроразметкой. Необходимо указать значение для поля url

Tags: php, wordpress-плагины, микроразметка

Здраствуйте. Гугл ругается на микроразметку плагина Wp-postratings.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде и код нашел но его исправить не знаю.
если подставить такую строчку - все ок:

```
<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://***-auto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo-300x300.jpg" />
</div>
```

но как это сделать динамически?

```
$site_logo = apply_filters( 'wp_postratings_site_logo', $site_logo );
$post_meta .= '<div style="display: none;" itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">';
$post_meta .= '<meta itemprop="name" content="' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . '" />';
$post_meta .= '<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">';
$post_meta .= '<meta itemprop="url" content="' . $site_logo . '" />';
$post_meta .= '</div>';
$post_meta .= '</div>';
```

Вроде и код нашел но его исправить не знаю. если подставить такую строчку - все ок: **  –

Comment: Вроде и код нашел но его исправить не знаю. если подставить такую строчку - все ок: **
<div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"><meta itemprop="url" content="https://***-auto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo-300x300.jpg" /></div>

Comment: Прикладывайте код в вопросе в виде текста. Нажмите на кнопку `править` в вопросе и вставьте соответствующий код в тело вопроса.